# Pandas.read_csv: backslash delimiter required?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, python-3.5

I'm reading a file directly into pandas with for some odd reason a backslash as delimiter. This is the code: Tried to escape the backslash with escapechar as an argument as I found somewhere but that does not work. How can I read this directly into pandas?

```
raw = pd.read_csv('http://language.media.mit.edu/data/public/unesco_langlang_20120722_iso639-3.txt', escapechar='\\', delimiter = "\\")
```

Comment: Can you add data sample? Maybe only removing `escapechar='\\'` is necessary.

Comment: No I added the escapechar after the delimiter did not work. This is the first line: abk\taze\t1. need to split it in three columns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think `escapechar` is your problem / fix. I read the file with the following code with no issues. The solution was to use variable whitespace as delimiter.

```
import pandas as pd

raw = pd.read_csv(r'C:\temp\unesco_langlang_20120722_iso639-3.txt',
                  delim_whitespace=True)

raw.head(10)

#   original_language target_language  num_translations
# 0               abk             aze                 1
# 1               abk             bul                 1
# 2               abk             deu                 1
# 3               abk             eng                 2
# 4               abk             est                 2
# 5               abk             fin                 1
# 6               abk             hin                 1
# 7               abk             kat                38
# 8               abk             kaz                 1
# 9               abk             kbd                 2
```